# Is it possible to get the scope chain programmatically?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the value of a variable using its name. But I also need to consider the scope stuff. For example, my user may write the following code:

```
var x = 20;
function func1(){
    var x = 30;
    return function(){
        return x;
    }
}

var func = func1();
```

Now they pass me this `func`, and also a string named `"x"`, and I need to evaluate `x` from the scope that `func` belongs to.

To be more clear, I need to implement a function, which takes two arguments, one is an object, the other is a string represent the variable name. The function need to return the value of the variable represented by the second argument from the scope that the first object belongs to.

```
function resolveValue(obj, name){
    //unimplemented;
}

resolveValue(func, "x"); //return 20 in this example.
```

I think this can be done if I can get the scope chain, but is this possible in javascript?

Comment: The first object will always only belong to the scope of the function. You should just try to avoid shadowing.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this. You don't have access to environment records of the current or any scope.